# How can I change the volume of the notification sounds on the AirPods Pro?

Tags: airpods

Using Siri or the iPhone volume controls, it is possible to change the volume of the audio content being played through the AirPods Pro. However, so far I have not found a way to change the volume of the notification sounds that are being played when I receive a message, when I switch to Transparency mode and back, etc.

I tried to call up Siri and change the volume while Siri is on screen, but this didn't work.

These noises are incredibly loud, and I really would like to reduce their volume. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

The sounds used when switching between transparency modes don’t seem to be adjustable, but notifications can be adjusted.

You can adjust the notification volume used both when AirPods are connected and when they are not (the volume will be the same for both).

Go to “Sounds & Haptics” in settings, and adjust the volume slider to your desired volume (note that the ringer preview will come out of your phone even with your AirPods in).

You can test the volume in your AirPods by previewing one of the “sounds and vibration patterns” below.

—

For more control, you can set volume of ringer and alerts to be set by the volume buttons (directly below the slider).

Comment: The slider doesn't seem to have an effect on the volume of the sounds that play when activating/deactivating Transparency mode. Possibly this has only an effect on Siri's voice or things like ringtones?

Comment: Good catch. My assumption is that you can’t change the volume of that. Added to top of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to adjust the volume as she is speaking. I had to message myself a long message and I was able to adjust her; I was having the same issue. Music and call volumes were fine, but she was whispering my notifications to me.

Answer (score 1):

Accessibility-PHYSICAL AND MOTOR-Airpods-TONE VOLUME(adjust the slider). Not sure if this will solve the problem because I have the airpods 3 and not pros, so no noise cancellation. But it does reduce the connection ping sound.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do it! Tell her to speak louder. It’s a speech notification not a sound notification